# Phone and google auth by firebase

Tags: react-native

in Phone auth when enter number and hit get error [App Id does not match requested project]
And in google auth get error A non-recoverable sign-in failure occurred

Comment: I follow rn-firebase and firebase to implement this..

Comment: If you're following a tutorial, you might want to provide a link as a reference, and also post your code.

Comment: Reference -https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/auth/social-auth , https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/implement-firebase-phone-authentication-in-react-native-apps-237959027611?gi=19da226dd7fc